# Harry Potter fanfiction where Harry poisons the whole Order of the Phoenix

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Looking for a fanfic where Harry Potter poisoned the Order of the Phoenix with Muggle poison. The poison was in cupcakes. Thanks if anyone recognises it.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fan-fiction-story-id-question) and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.